# Stability of $x(n) = A x(n-1)+b$

Tags: z-transform, poles-zeros, matrix, stability, causality

I am looking at the following system:
$x(n) = A x(n-1) + b$
where x and b are vectors and A is a matrix. How can I derive the stability and causality conditions for such a system using Z transform?

If I apply Z transform to each element of x, I have:
$X(z) = A z^{-1} X(z) + b$
Therefore, $(I - Az^{-1})X(z) = b$. Then,
$X(z) = (I - Az^{-1})^{-1} b$.

Is this correct? What are the conditions for stability and causality?

Comment: Is $b$ time-varying, or did you perhaps mean $x_n = A x_{n-1} + b u_n$, where $u_n$ is the system input?

Comment: This looks so very much like the canonical state-space representation (aside from $b$ not being a constant multiplier to an input $u_n$) that I'm wondering -- is it homework?